# Can bash be used to rename by pattern?

Tags: bash, perl, rename

I have files:

```
alpha_123_abc_file.txt
beta_456_def_file.txt
gamma_789_ghi_file.txt
```

Is there a way to rename all to cut the parts after the first _ character? To become:

```
123_abc_file.txt
456_def_file.txt
789_ghi_file.txt
```

I've looked into the perl tool but I an unsure if it has the capability to search out a pattern like that.

Comment: Given the input file names you posted, what should happen if `123_abc_file.txt` already exists when you try to rename `alpha_123_abc_file.txt`?

Comment: @EdMorton I don't think a file conflict will be an issue. The files are in a temporary project directory so there are only a few at a time in it.

Comment: Perl is a general-purpose programming language, so yes, it has this capability. (I could say the same thing about "the Python tool", "the Java tool", "the C++ tool", etc.) Are you asking us to write a Perl program for you?

Comment: @user1081491 it only takes 2. If you have `foo_123_abc_file.txt` and `bar_123_abc_file.txt` in that directory then the first rename will be OK but the 2nd one will try to overwrite the first.

Comment: @ruakh I'm trying to figure it out myself but I'm having trouble finding the code to do a rename like that. All I've found says that perl will rename a keyphrase like the _ character, but I don't know how to make it only apply to the first _ character.

Comment: @user1081491: Re: "perl will rename a keyphrase like the _ character": Do you have a link to what you're referring to? Because as I said, Perl is a general-purpose programming language. It can rename anything to anything, using whatever arbitrary logic you might want to use to set the filenames. This isn't a "find the code" situation, it's a "write the code" situation.

Comment: $ rename '\_(.*)' *.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in *_*; do echo mv -- "$file" "${file#*_}"; done
```

Remove the `echo` when you're done testing and ready to actually do the `mv`.